# Right to left menu sub-menu is displayed left to right

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a problem with menus in C#.

My project is in Right-To-Left Language so the menus are right to left. but the problem is that when I run the project sub menus are displayed Left-To-Right

I am not able to solve this problem from a day.

[image: Menu and Sub Menu in Visual Studio]

[image: Menu and Sub Menu while Running]

Comment: The only difference I can see is the + icon being on the wrong side. Is that the issue? Please post your code to help people troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @Alex - that's very clearly the problem..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug, but if you set the form's property RightToLeft to No and set menustrip RightToLeft to Yes then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Click on your command (كزارش نوبسي) To Select it. Then go to the **Properties**, 
and change the Property (**RightToLeft**) to (**No**), and change it back to (**Yes**) again.

Then Run your project, you will see your problem has been solved.